# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mercantile'

Tags: python

i install mercantile by use "pip install mercantile"
and give me in command

```
Requirement already satisfied: mercantile in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=3.0 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from mercantile) (7.1.2)
```

and when i run import mercantile in python
they give me error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mercantile'
```

What should I do, please

Comment: `pip install mercantile && echo "import mercantile" | python` works for me, so there has to be something going on with your environment.  My guess is that you are installing the module into one version of Python but then running a different version.  Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?  Are you using virtualenvs? You're on Windows, which makes it harder for me to know how to help you.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple python installations. Make sure you are using the python executable in `c:\python38`.